# How to access generated key for clojure jdbc insert

Tags: jdbc, clojure

How can I obtain the generated key from the returned map. It seems to end with "()" and I can't seem to use it like a regular key.

```
(defn create-map-db [mapname]
  (insert! db-settings :MAP_TABLE {:M_NAME mapname})
  )

(first (create-map-db "Moskau"))
=> {:scope_identity() 3}

(type (first (create-map-db "Moskau")))
=> clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap

(get (first (create-map-db "Moskau")) :scope_identity())
=> ()

(get (first (create-map-db "Moskau")) :scope_identity)
=> nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could see something like the following as the most portable solution:

```
(first (vals (first (create-map-db "Moskau"))))
```

But if you really want you can probably access the key directly using:

```
(def generated-key (keyword "scope_identity()"))
(generated-key (first (create-map-db "Moskau")))
```

Which is also usable to get *all* generated keys:

```
(map generated-key (create-map-db "Moskau"))
```